# Type mismatch in function arguments

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write this small piece of code but I can't get it work. I have a very little experience in Rust, especially with lifetimes.

I have reproduced the error in a smaller script:

```
fn main() {
    let app = App {
        name: &String::from("Davide"),
    };
    app.run();
}

struct App<'a> {
    name: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    fn run(self) {
        let result = App::validator_1(App::validator_2(App::box_command()))(self);
        println!("{}", result)
    }

    fn validator_1(next: Box<Fn(App) -> String>) -> Box<Fn(App) -> String> {
        Box::new(move |app: App| -> String { next(app) })
    }

    fn validator_2(next: Box<Fn(App) -> String>) -> Box<Fn(App) -> String> {
        Box::new(move |app: App| -> String { next(app) })
    }

    fn box_command() -> Box<Fn(App) -> String> {
        Box::new(App::command)
    }

    fn command(self) -> String {
        format!("Hello {}!", self.name)
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get this error:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         Box::new(App::command)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(App<'r>) -> _`
...
30 |     fn command(self) -> String {
   |     -------------------------- found signature of `fn(App<'_>) -> _`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(App<'r>) -> std::string::String`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <fn(App<'_>) -> std::string::String {App<'_>::command} as std::ops::FnOnce<(App<'r>,)>>::Output == std::string::String`
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         Box::new(App::command)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(App<'r>) -> std::string::String`
```

I understand that the problem is somehow related to the lifetime of `name` in `App` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: IMO this is more complicated than it needs to be; why not just let `App` own the `String` instead of borrowing it?

Comment: Hi @ljedrz, this is just a simplified example. In the real case, I can't substitute `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the `command` function does not match with what `box_command` is expected to return.

`box_command` should have the following body:

```
fn box_command() -> Box<Fn(App) -> String> {
    Box::new(move |app: App| -> String { app.command() })
}
```

The compiler is expecting an invocation which returns a `String`. The above change will allow `self` from the following statement to be passed as the `app` argument. Thus `app.command()` satisfies the entire flow and returns `String` from the invocation chain.

```
let result = App::validator_1(App::validator_2(App::box_command()))(self);
```